# Absolute value of real numbers and inequality

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers. Show that

$\vert a-b\vert < \epsilon \Rightarrow \vert a\vert<\vert b\vert+\epsilon$

for $\epsilon>0$.

Looks quite easy but I'm not getting it. I tried to use triangular inequality in many forms but it doensn't come.

Comment: Think reverse triangle inequality $|a-b|\ge\big||a|-|b|\big|\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the idea -- this is indeed the Triangle Inequality: $$|a| = |(a-b) + b| \leq |a-b| + |b| < \epsilon + |b|.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$|a - b| < \epsilon $$
$$|a| = |(a-b) + b| < |a-b| + |b| $$
Therefore by using (1) in (2)
$$|a| < |b| + \epsilon$$